# Oracle: Decimal and rounding

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, rounding

I have a value in the table 0.0821, and I want to convert it to 8.21.

My SQL query is `to_char(round(prdll_yr2.rate_chg_pct_qty *100 ),'9.99')`

But it returns  8.00 instead of 8.21.

Comment: Just multiplying by 100 got me the the value prdll_yr2.rate_chg_pct_qty *100

Comment: ok.  But if your value was 0.08211 what result would you want from your query?  8.21 or 8.211? Also do you want a numeric data type back or a character?

Comment: I want to return 8.21

Comment: multiplying by 100 woudln't do it then, you may need to round the value then depending on the scale and precision of rate_chg_pct_qty

Answer (score 6):

```
to_char(round(0.0821 *100,2 ),'9.99')
```

`to_char(round(prdll_yr2.rate_chg_pct_qty *100,2 ),'9.99')`

you're missing the number of decimals to display on the round...  it will [default to 0 if omitted](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm)

or for an example:

```
select to_char(round(0.0821 *100,2 ),'9.99') from dual;
```

Results in: 8.21

```
select to_char(round(0.0821 *100),'9.99') from dual;
```

Results in: 8.00

----------------------------GIVEN NEW INFORMATION:---------------------------

```
to_char(round(0.0821 *100,2 ),'9,999.99')
```

Adjust the 9,999.99 [format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)  to be equal to the scale and precision of the allowed in the database.  so if your value is Numeric(9,5)  this implies 4 leading numbers followed by 5 decimal places.  Since you're multiplying by 100 the largest value you could have is 6 positions before the decimal so format of 999,999.99 and the 3rd decimal would be "Rounded"

Comment: when i do select to_char(round(0.0821 *100,2 ),'9.99') from dual;  Result is displayed in following format : #####

Comment: @user1683763 - when you run that exact query, or when you use your table data? Do you have a value >= 0.1? That would convert to 10.0 (or higher), which is too many digits for that number format, and that would be displayed as hashes (by SQL*Plus). If you need to handle those make it `'99.99'`, or `'999.99'`, etc. depending on the largest possible value.

Comment: You don't need to call `ROUND` in this case as your `TO_CHAR` format does that anyway.

Comment: agreed. but not knowing what data type the OP wanted the result in I left it all in place.